# Deal x Number of Hands of Cards in Clojure - vs Partition

Tags: algorithm, clojure

What is the most idiomatic and efficient way within Clojure to deal a hand of cards to a certain number of players. Clojure's partition doesn't actually simulate real world physical dealing of cards.

Note: I'd like to be able to deal to any number of players. Doesn't matter if cards are fully dealt unequally. I'd like to be very generic as to handle sub 52 cards... or multiple decks mixed.

Example data structure of available cards and empty function signature:

```
(def sample-cards 
    [[:5 :Heart]
    [:8 :Spade]
    [:7 :Club]
    [:9 :Diamond]
    [:J :Spade]
    [:Q :Heart]
    [:5 :Spade]
    [:8 :Club]
    [:6 :Diamond]])


(defn deal-cards [players deck]
    ; some logic/looping 
    ; then return give the args 4 and sample-cards
    [[[:5 :Heart] [:J :Spade] [:6 :Diamond]]
    [[:8 :Spade] [:Q :Heart]]
    [[:7 :Club]  [:5 :Spade]]
    [[:9 :Diamond] [:8 :Club]]])
```

Comment: I was thinking if you could get access to an index int as you loop through the deck (a shuffled deck)... that you could use modulus to decide which hand they would go into.

Comment: Both of my solutions use an index in the loop.

Comment: I saw that @AlanThompson was just making sure anyone else looking at this would at least consider that... or not, if they knew better. Most of my "whats possible" with functional concepts is the smattering of ideas that have made it into EcmaScript, Python or C#'s LINQ. Love what I see in Clojure and just readjusting my brain to think in more LISPy syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a fairly compact implementation using lazy sequences:

```
(defn deal-cards [n deck]
  (map (partial take-nth n)
       (take n (iterate rest deck))))
```

An example:

```
(deal-cards 4 sample-cards)
;; => (([:5 :Heart] [:J :Spade] [:6 :Diamond]) ([:8 :Spade] [:Q :Heart]) ([:7 :Club] [:5 :Spade]) ([:9 :Diamond] [:8 :Club]))
```

Comment: Cute! Maybe `(->> deck (iterate rest) (take n) (map (partial take-nth n)))`?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you really just want to force that order and consume the full deck (and not just shuffle the cards and then distribute, which `partition` will do just fine -- at least if there are more cards than *players* times *initial card in hands*), the following function does that:

```
(defn deal-for [player-count cards]
  (reduce (fn [acc [idx card]]
            (update acc idx (fnil conj []) card))
          []
          (map vector (cycle (range player-count)) cards)))
```

The idea is to cycle the indices to which player a card will be given to.

Comment: Nice and concise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Clojure's partition doesn't actually simulate real world physical dealing of cards.

I don't understand that. Would partition not work if the cards were [shuffled](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/shuffle) first?

```clj
(partition players (shuffle deck))
```

Note that any remaining cards in the deck are not dealt, and if you care about that then either 1) compare the deck to the dealt cards and find the difference, or 2) use a loop as you say (probably using `reduce`) to explicitly hand out cards and remove them from the deck as you go.

Maybe you have a specific definition of "dealing" that isn't "distribute a set of cards randomly to a set of players"?

Comment: the `partition` is no good here, since it doesn't count the remainder of cards/players. `partition-all` also fails because it tries to make full sets, and then adds the rest. `take-nth` with offsets could do the trick, but it would have deck * players complexity.

Comment: My concern with partition is I'm not sure if you should use something like that when doing Monte Carlo Simulations. Something about not doing what a dealer actually does... doesn't smell right.

Comment: Doesn't a dealer shuffle before each hand?

Comment: @BuddyJoe The difference I can see is that there is no relation between the available cards and the cards that are not dealt, because I am treating decks as sets of cards, and some operations aren't compatible with that. But depending on exactly what you're looking at doing, this is the most natural model I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn deal-cards
      [num-players deck]
      (loop [deck-remaining (shuffle deck)
             ; vvv sample start value:  {0 #{}, 1 #{}, 2 #{}, 3 #{}}
             player-hands   (zipmap (range num-players) (repeat #{}))
             player-idx     0]
        (if (empty? deck-remaining)
          player-hands
          (let [card (first deck-remaining)
                deck-remaining-next (rest deck-remaining )
                player-hands-next (update player-hands player-idx conj card)
                player-idx-next (mod (inc player-idx) 4)]
            (recur
              deck-remaining-next player-hands-next player-idx-next)))))

(dotest
  (let [sample-cards [[:5 :Heart]
                      [:8 :Spade]
                      [:7 :Club]
                      [:9 :Diamond]
                      [:J :Spade]
                      [:Q :Heart]
                      [:5 :Spade]
                      [:8 :Club]
                      [:6 :Diamond]]
        result (deal-cards 4 sample-cards)]
    (spyx-pretty result)
    ))
```

with results like:

```
result => 
{0 #{[:8 :Spade] [:6 :Diamond] [:5 :Heart]},
 1 #{[:5 :Spade] [:Q :Heart]},
 2 #{[:9 :Diamond] [:8 :Club]},
 3 #{[:7 :Club] [:J :Spade]}}

result => 
{0 #{[:5 :Heart] [:5 :Spade] [:9 :Diamond]},
 1 #{[:7 :Club] [:Q :Heart]},
 2 #{[:8 :Club] [:J :Spade]},
 3 #{[:8 :Spade] [:6 :Diamond]}}

result => 
{0 #{[:Q :Heart] [:9 :Diamond] [:8 :Club]},
 1 #{[:7 :Club] [:J :Spade]},
 2 #{[:6 :Diamond] [:5 :Heart]},
 3 #{[:8 :Spade] [:5 :Spade]}}
```

---

**Update**

Here is a version using `reduce` that is shorter than `loop/recur`

```
(defn deal-cards
      [num-players deck]
      (let [deck          (vec (shuffle deck))
            idxs          (cycle (range num-players))
            labeled-cards (zipmap deck idxs)
            result        (reduce
                            (fn [out-map [card idx]]
                              (update out-map idx conj card))
                            (zipmap (range num-players) (repeat #{}))
                            labeled-cards)]
        result))
```

Comment: Thanks. Will have to look into tupelo.

Comment: I see no reason to pull out loop..recur for something like this.

Comment: I forgot the name of `shuffle` at first (was only looking under `rand-*`).  Also forgot to use `cycle` in the first iteration.  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

i would go with something like this:

```
(defn deal [n-players deck]
  (let [players (into [] (repeat n-players []))]
    (reduce (fn [players [card idx]] (update players (rem idx n-players) conj card))
            players
            (map vector deck (range)))))

user> (deal 5 (range 13))
;;=> [[0 5 10] [1 6 11] [2 7 12] [3 8] [4 9]]
```

here you just circularly update the players' hands adding new card to the next player each time based on remainder of `index/number-of-players`